# CountIf in google sheets

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets, formulas, countif

**The Goal**

Basically, I want to compare A6 to range Responses!C:C and return a count of non blanks in columns Responses!F:F

**I'm using this formula**

```
=COUNTIF(responses!D:D, "=A6", responses!F:F)
```

**What I've done**

In the example, I'm trying to check column D in the responses sheet for a string in cell A6 of the dashboard sheet. If the string exists in the column D of the responses sheet, then I want a count of the items in column F. I expect 0 to be returned for the NJROTC item.

**Request**

Can someone please review my formula and let me know what I'm doing wrong OR if there is a better solution than the COUNTIF function?

**Video Explaining the Problem**

http://youtu.be/J_ados6Ksq4

[image]
[image]

Comment: After watching your youtube video your missing a little detail in your question. You want to compare A6 to range Responses!D:D and return a count of non blanks in columns Responses!F: [not sure your last column of data].

Comment: My first question is does each response only show up once in Responses!D:D?

Comment: @AxGryndr, No. They may show up more than once. I want to display the 'count' for the number of responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(ISTEXT(VLOOKUP($A6,responses!$D:$M,3, FALSE)),"Yes","No")
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Just a syntax issue; change `"=A6"` to simply `A6` (you could also use `"="&A6` but that is functionally no different and more key strokes).

Comment: Thanks for offering to help. I used `=COUNTIF(responses!D:D, "="&A6, responses!F:F)` but I receive this error when I do `Error: Wrong number of arguments to COUNTIF. Expected 2 arguments, but got 3 arguments.`

Any ideas?